# Sscanf will read ints but not doubles (c)?

Tags: c, struct, scanf, c-strings, conversion-specifier

I have the following stored in a char array

```
"1, 1.0, 1.000, 1.0000"
```

I am trying to parse it into an int and three doubles with the following

```
sscanf(myString, "%d %lf %lf %lf", &(myStruct->I1), &(myStruct->D1), &(myStruct->D2), &(myStruct->D3);
printf("%d %lf %lf %lf", myStruct->I1, myStruct->D1, myStruct->D2, myStruct->D3);
```

outputs

```
1 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

Comment: Make it into [mcve]. Shouldn't be hard

Comment: What would consume the commas?

Comment: Always check the return value of `scanf` and its relatives.

Comment: `sscanf(myString, "%d ,%lf ,%lf ,%lf", ... )`. Doing it like that will catch any whitespace *before* the comma, while any whitespace *after* the comma is caught automatically by the `%lf` specifier.

Comment: Yes thank you! I was missing the commas!

Answer (score 1):

The source string contains commas. So you need to change the format string in the call of `sscanf`.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    char myString[] = "1, 1.0, 1.000, 1.0000";
    struct myStruct
    {
        int I1;
        double D1;
        double D2; 
        double D3;
    } myStruct;
    
    sscanf( myString, "%d%*[ ,]%lf%*[ ,]%lf%*[ ,]%lf", 
            &myStruct.I1,&myStruct.D1, &myStruct.D2, &myStruct.D3 );
             
    printf( "%d, %.1f, %.2f, %.3f\n", 
            myStruct.I1, myStruct.D1, myStruct.D2, myStruct.D2 );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1, 1.0, 1.00, 1.000
```

The format string can look even simpler like

```
"%d ,%lf ,%lf ,%lf"
```

Pay attention to that the length modifier `l` is redundant in the conversion specifier `%lf` when it is used in `printf`.